# How to create AWS AMI from created instance using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am setting up an aws instance with wordpress installation and want to create an AMI using created instance. Below I attach my code.

```
provider "aws" {

    region = "${var.region}"
    access_key = "${var.access_key}"
    secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
}

resource  "aws_instance" "test-wordpress" {

    ami = "${var.image_id}"
    instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
    key_name = "test-web"
    #associate_public_ip_address = yes

    user_data = <<-EOF

      #!/bin/bash

      sudo yum update -y
      sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
      sudo yum install -y httpd mariadb-server
      cd /var/www/html
      sudo echo "healthy" > healthy.html
      sudo wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
      sudo tar -xzf latest.tar.gz
      sudo cp -r wordpress/* /var/www/html/
      sudo rm -rf wordpress
      sudo rm -rf latest.tar.gz
      sudo chmod -R 755 wp-content
      sudo chown -R apache:apache wp-content
      sudo service httpd start
      sudo chkconfig httpd on

      EOF


    tags = {
      Name = "test-Wordpress-Server"
    }
} 


resource  "aws_ami_from_instance" "test-wordpress-ami" {
    name               = "test-wordpress-ami"
    source_instance_id = "${aws_instance.test-wordpress.id}"

  depends_on = [
      aws_instance.test-wordpress,
      ]

  tags = {
      Name = "test-wordpress-ami"
  }

}
```

AMI will be created but When I use that AMI to create an another instance wordpress installation not in there. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Hashicorp (makers of Terraform) also produce [Packer](https://packer.io/), which is purpose-made for preparing AMIs and other machine images. It will likely offer a better experience than trying to hack together the same thing in Terraform.

Comment: Understood that Packer is the recipe used to build AMIS. Nevertheless, in his case, perhaps there is a requirement to use terraform only, e.g. only the terraform executable is available in a company provided server. In effect, as the name suggests, “aws_ami_from_instance” should do exactly that: build an AMI from the current state of the ebs volume and the block device mapping configured in the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

So you can search for AMI by your tag as described in [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html)

In your case:

```
data "aws_ami" "example" {
  executable_users = ["self"]
  most_recent      = true
  owners           = ["self"]

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["test-wordpress-ami"]
  }
}
```

and then refer ID as `${data.aws_ami.example.image_id}`

Comment: `data "aws_instance" "test-wordpress-instance" {'
 filter {
   name = "tag:Name"
   values = ["Test-Wordpress-Server"]
   depends_on = ["aws_instance.test-wordpress"]
 }
}` configured like this. But It doesn't create instance in the begining and looking for created instances. Getting the error. **Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.** Is there a way to force create the instance before executing data source?

Comment: you used wrong tag. Your ami's tag is "test-wordpress-ami" not "Test-Wordpress-Server"

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create AMI images i think is using Packer, also from Hashicorp like terraform.

What is Packer?

> Provision Infrastructure with Packer Packer is HashiCorp's open-source tool for creating machine images from source
> configuration. You can configure Packer images with an operating
> system and software for your specific use-case.

Packer creates an instance with temporary keypair, security_group and IAM roles. In the provisioner "shell" are custom inline commands possible. Afterwards you can use this ami with your terraform code.

A sample script could look like this:

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    amazon = {
      version = ">= 0.0.2"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/amazon"
    }
  }
}

source "amazon-ebs" "linux" {
  # AMI Settings
  ami_name                      = "ami-oracle-python3"
  instance_type                 = "t2.micro"
  source_ami                    = "ami-xxxxxxxx"
  ssh_username                  = "ec2-user"
  associate_public_ip_address   = false
  ami_virtualization_type       = "hvm"
  subnet_id                     = "subnet-xxxxxx" 
  
  launch_block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    volume_size = 8
    volume_type = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted = false
  }

  # Profile Settings
  profile                       = "xxxxxx"
  region                        = "eu-central-1"
}

build {
  sources = [
    "source.amazon-ebs.linux"
  ]
  provisioner "shell" {
    inline = [
        "export no_proxy=localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can find documentation [here](https://www.packer.io/docs).